# Cannot Attach Databases or Create new one in ssms

Tags: sql-server, windows-8.1, ssms

I can not attach a database, and create one either. SSMS keeps telling me 'Cannot show requested dialog'; What should I do? I am using SQL Server 2008 r2 on Windows 8.1 OS.

---

Error Message:

---

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

### Cannot show requested dialog.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Parameter name: nColIndex

### Actual value was -1. (Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl)

BUTTONS:

### OK*

---

Comment: Please add whole error message. The issue will be written in text next to this sentence.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if database owner is null.

Check if database owner is null

```
SELECT name,
       suser_sname(sid)
FROM   sysdatabases
```

This will reveal NULLs for the databases in the instance, so set the owner to SA using the following:

```
USE DBName
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

Comment: I see no 'NULL's there I am using windows authentication not sa. I didnt even created one db because i can't; This happened right after installation to a new laptop. I also have an mdf file from other pc, and i am not able to attach it to ssms too.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution to it. Since I have installed the sql-server through the builtin windows administrator; sysadmin role was not granted for the windows user I am using for development. Now, I can attach or create sql-dbs :(.